# Text file diff library (MS licensed)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, diff

Does anyone know if there a way to tap into visual studios diff libraries to extend the functionality of my projects?

I know that there are open source solutions for file diffing that I will consider if I cant find an adequate Microsoft implementation of it. Visual Studio comes with nice diff feature that it uses to compare source files.

I want to use code that is MS licensed. It seems that visual studio fulfills that requirement and has the feature I need.

It seems like this would be a useful extension library that maybe .NET should have in it, or already does?

Any ideas?

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDiff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio diff window (new to Visual Studio 2012) uses the [`IDifferenceBufferFactoryService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh698406.aspx) to create the [`IDifferenceBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.differencing.idifferencebuffer.aspx) it displays. From there it uses the [`ITextDifferencingSelectorService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.differencing.itextdifferencingselectorservice.aspx) to get the appropriate [`ITextDifferencingService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.differencing.itextdifferencingservice.aspx) for each side. From there you'll have to do a good bit of reading to understand the API. :)

If you are creating a Visual Studio 2012 extension, the API you are interested is available in the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Differencing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd886715.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the lead. I'm going to investigate. How did you determine this?